# In C++,what's the order of constructor and operator?

Tags: c++

It is a problem for the ECE220 final exam

```cpp
#include <stdio.h>
class THING {
    int x;
public:
    THING() :x(1) {
        printf("ONE ");
    }
    THING(int val) : x(val) {
        printf("%d ", val);
    }
    THING& operator=(const THING &t) {
        this->x = t.x + 10;
        printf("= %d", this->x);
        return *this;
    }
    friend THING operator+(const THING &t, const THING &u) {
        printf("-> ");
        return THING(t.x * u.x);
    }
};
THING* function() {
    printf("line 1: ");
    THING t(1); // t.x is 1
    printf("\nline 2: ");
    THING u = (t + 3) + 5; // u.x is 15 // in here operator t will not be used, instead it will call a construction function //copy construction 
            
}
int main(int argc, char const *argv[]) {
    function();
    return 0;
}
```

output

line 1: 1

line 2: 5 3 -> 3 -> 15

line 3: 16 -> 240

the line2 output can be 3 -> 3 5 -> 15 which is also a solution for this problem.

I don't understand why  5 3 -> 3 -> 15 is also correct.

any insight about the order in an expression?

Comment: The [order of evaluation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/eval_order) of arguments to a function is unspecified. So with `(t + 3) + 5`, the compiler is free to evaluate the `(t + 3)` first _or_ it can convert `5` to `THING` first and then evaluate `(t + 3)`.

Comment: You could also gain some insight by running in the debugger with breakpoints in each function.

Comment: `THING u = (t + 3) + 5;` is an initialization. There are [a lot of different types of initialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/initialization) and [initializations can get weird](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7DTlWPgX6zs), but the assignment operator will not be used because there is no object to assign to yet. To exercise the assignment operator, you need two steps, construction followed by assignment. `THING u; u = (t + 3) + 5;`